# Zero gaussian curvature implies developable

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

I was thinking about the fact that if a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is locally isometric to the plane, then its Gaussian curvature is $K=0$ (which is a direct consequence of Theorema Egregium)

I have read on Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) that if a surface has a Gaussian curvature $K=0$, then it is developable.

I have the understanding that a
surface is developable $\iff$ it is locally isometric to a plane. Is that correct ?

If so, a little help on the proof that "$K=0$ implies developable" would be appreciated. If not a little clarification or a counterexample would be much helpful.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is your definition of "developable" here?

Comment: There are developable surfaces (e.g., cones and tangent developables) that have singularities. But if you restrict to smooth (nonsingular) points, yes, it's true that $K$ is identically zero if and only if the surface is locally isometric to the plane.

Comment: Okay thanks. So how do we show that if $K$ is identically zero then then the surface is locally isometric to the plane? 
I would start with something along the lines of this: let $S$  a surface such that $K= 0$ identically and $p \in S$, with $(f,U)$ a local parametrisation such that $q \in U $ with $f(q) = p$. Then by definition, $f$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image. I guess the only thing left to show is that the first fundamental form induced by $f$ is the identity.  Since we have $K =0$ $\iff \det(II) = 0 \iff eg-f^2 = 0$, my idea would be to continue from here, does that make sense ?

Comment: @jffi You won't be able to choose an arbitrary parameterization, since the first fundamental form won't generally be the identity. Instead, there exist a special class of local parameterizations (called *normal coordinates*) which have this property. As far as I know, this requires some nontrivial construction/computation to prove; see for instance section 4-6 of Do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces*.

Comment: @Kajelad Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for. It's in fact an application of Minding's theorem to $K = 0$.